# Providing a generic PartnerEntity for SAML federation of SAML in Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, saml, federation

We have a SaaS application where our IDP is Azure B2C.

We are using Azure B2C to allow enterprise SSO with external thru federation (SAML). Using B2C it required to setup a ClaimsProvider per enterprise company. This does expose the PartnerEntity.

Example (Claims technical profile):

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="Contoso-SAML2">
      <DisplayName>Contooso</DisplayName>
      <Description>Login with your AD FS account</Description>
      <Protocol Name="SAML2"/>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="RequestsSigned">false</Item>
        <Item Key="ResponsesSigned">false</Item>
        <Item Key="WantsEncryptedAssertions">false</Item>
        <Item Key="PartnerEntity">https://login.microsoftonline.com/..tenantid../federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=..appid..</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SAMLSigningCert"/>
      </CryptographicKeys>
      ...
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

We are trying to attempt creating a generic federation policy where the partner entity is generic - not adding one technical profile per external federation partner.

Example:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>SAML</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Contoso-SAML2">
      <DisplayName>SAML</DisplayName>
      <Description>Login with your AD FS account</Description>
      <Protocol Name="SAML2"/>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="RequestsSigned">false</Item>
        <Item Key="ResponsesSigned">false</Item>
        <Item Key="WantsEncryptedAssertions">false</Item>
        <Item Key="PartnerEntity"> what to add here for generic ??? </Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SAMLSigningCert"/>
      </CryptographicKeys>
      ...
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

how to configure the  what to add here for generic ??? ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to support SAML federation to **any Entra ID tenant** using a single technical profile then the entity URL is https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml (taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/saml-protocol-reference)).

If you want to support SAML federation to **any arbitrary SAML IdP** using a single technical profile then unfortunately you can't.

Each identity provider will have its own SAML metadata endpoint, that's what you're configuring in `PartnerEntity`. If all your IdPs have the same metadata endpoint then you only have one IdP and so you only need one technical profile.

If you want to define a common technical profile that's shared by all IdPs and want to be able to add new technical profiles for each IdP that just set the `PartnerEntity` then you can use [`IncludeTechnicalProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/technicalprofiles#include-technical-profile):

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="Idp-Saml-Base">
  <DisplayName>Common</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="SAML2"/>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="RequestsSigned">false</Item>
    <Item Key="ResponsesSigned">false</Item>
    <Item Key="WantsEncryptedAssertions">false</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SAMLSigningCert"/>
  </CryptographicKeys>
  ...
</TechnicalProfile>

<TechnicalProfile Id="Idp-Contoso">
  <DisplayName>Contoso</DisplayName>
  <Description>Login with your AD FS account</Description>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="PartnerEntity">https://login.microsoftonline.com/..tenantid../federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=..appid..</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Idp-Saml-Base" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. 

Re. If you want to support SAML federation to any Entra ID tenant:
Makes perfect sense - we would label the common Entra ID as "Entra". This is common and does not expose our app and customer endpoint.

Re. If you want to support SAML federation to any arbitrary SAML IdP:
Understood. A follow-up would be if we can "hide" the name and details from the UI? Not really optimal to show "Spotify", "Starbucks", "Mercedes" on our login pages, as anyone would know then they are our customers.

Comment: @RasmusVesterskovF. yep, you can use the "[enabled for user journeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/technicalprofiles#enabled-for-user-journeys)" feature to disable technical profiles which will stop them showing in the UI. For example, you could use a `domain_hint` passed in as part of the authorisation request to control which technical profile(s) are visible and get executed. If only one technical profile applies then B2C will automatically execute it.

Comment: Just to add, that's evaluated dynamically as well, so it's based on the state of the claim when the technical profile would be executed in the journey, it's not something you enable/disable globally ahead of time.